# Unable to pack files/can't find missing files

Tags: texturing, file-browser

I'm using **Blender 2.78** to mesh clothing (obj file imports) created using CLO3D software.

For several months, I'm been making clothes, exporting them as objs, importing them into Blender, and meshing them for a game. However, this week, I'm having an unusual problem.

Some of the clothing that I've made and exported use mesh fabric properties.
The properties render properly in Blender.

[image]

I noticed 2 changes:

1. The mesh portion shows up in the 3D view port as a purple patch on the obj when before it showed up as whatever color I had the mesh fabric set to (usually black).

[image]

2. When I have my obj imported and I try to save my blend file I get the following error message:

> Unable to pack file, file source (CLO fabric title.jpg) not found.

Which is strange because I have been able to properly mesh items containing mesh fabric from CLO's program in the past. I always use Blender 2.78 and I haven't changed my settings. CLO3D is installed on my computer including the folding containing the fabric .zfab files (which is typically what Blender uses to recognize the fabric properties).

I don't know what prompted this change. I have tried resetting my computer and reinstalling Blender and CLO3D, but the error still remains. I have no idea how to remedy this and when I try to find missing files in the external data menu, it keeps saying files not found.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Blender 2.78 is rather old, does the issue appear in the latest 2.81 version?

Comment: I haven't used any of the newer blender versions. For a year, I've been able to successfully mesh my items made in both Marvelous Designer and CLO3D using blender 2.78. I looked at Blender 2.80's interface and I didn't like it. The settings that I use for meshing aren't the same and I have a lot more trouble making them. Just last month, I was able to mesh about 4 items that had mesh fabric properties exported from CLO3D. Most of my clothes use the default fabric properties, so I didn't notice the change until I tried to mesh something with mesh fabric properties a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because Clo no longer supports JPEG files for fabrics.
You now have to spend $5K for their fabric kit to render your own textiles.